# How to cross-reference a table that uses adjustwidth?

Tags: tables, changepage

I set up a `table` environment and move it a bit to the left via `adjustwidth` from the `changepage` package. However, if I want to reference it via `\cref` from the `cleveref` package, after compilation, "??" is displayed instead of the reference. What am I doing wrong in the minimal example below? Note that the correct label appears as soon as the `adjustwidth` environment is commented out.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!ht]                                                                                                                      
    \begin{adjustwidth}{-2.5in}{0in}
        \centering
        \caption{caption}
        \begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
            \hline
            \multirow{2}{*}{first two rows} & 1 \\
            & 2 \\
            \hline
            third row & 3 \\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}                                                                                                                   
    \end{adjustwidth} 
    \label{label}                                                                                                                       
\end{table}
Here, I want to reference it: \cref{label}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Moving the label right after the caption seems to solve it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have `label` on the wrong place, Move it immediately after `\caption`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!ht]
    \begin{adjustwidth}{-2.5in}{0in}
        \centering
        \caption{caption}
        \label{label}
        \begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
            \hline
            \multirow{2}{*}{first two rows} & 1 \\
            & 2 \\
            \hline
            third row & 3 \\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{adjustwidth}
\end{table}
Here, I want to reference it: \cref{label}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT:**

BTW, your setting for `adjustwidth` cause that its content protrude out of left board of page. You need to reduce it for example as is done in the second example in the next MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{cleveref}

%---------------- Show page layout. Don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{lipsum}% For dummy text. Don't use in a real document

\begin{document}
\lipsum[11]

\begin{table}[!ht]
    \begin{adjustwidth}{-2in}{}
        \centering
        \caption{\lipsum[66]}
        \label{label}
        \begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
            \hline
            \multirow{2}{*}{first two rows} & 1 \\
            & 2 \\
            \hline
            third row & 3 \\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
        
\rule{\linewidth}{1pt}
    \end{adjustwidth}
\end{table}
Here, I want to reference it: \cref{label}.
\begin{table}[!ht]
    \begin{adjustwidth}{-\dimexpr\oddsidemargin+\marginparwidth}{}
        \centering
        \caption{\lipsum[66]}
        \label{label}
        \begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
            \hline
            \multirow{2}{*}{first two rows} & 1 \\
            & 2 \\
            \hline
            third row & 3 \\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
        
\rule{\linewidth}{1pt}
    \end{adjustwidth}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines indicate page layout)

Comment: @AKG, see edited answer!

Comment: thanks a lot for the solution and the additional information!

Comment: @AKG, you are welcome!